# jQuery flot with php and mysql does not display chart

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, charts, flot

I am trying to create a chart with flot using data taken from a mysql database

```
     <div id="flot-placeholder" style="width:800px;height:450px"></div>
    <?php  
          $host = "localhost";
          $uname = "user";
          $pass = "mypass";
          $database = "mydb";
          $connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass) or die("connection in not ready <br>");
          $result=mysql_select_db($database) or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

          $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM dailysales");
          $lineset=array();

          while($lrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
          {
                 $lineset[] = array($lrow['quantity'],$lrow['paid']);
          }

         ?>


 <script language="javascript">
 var plotdata =  <?php echo json_encode($lineset);?>;

 var data,options;

 data=[[plotdata]];

 document.write(plotdata);
 options={};
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"),
            data,
    options);
});
</script>
```

This shows the chart but the chart itself is empty. Printing the value of plotdata does give the correct values as 210,1000.00,30,3500.00. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `plotdata` is already an array and then you put it in an array twice when assigning it to `data`. Try

```
data = [plotdata];
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) for more info.